# Java HTTPClient: Is closeIdleConnections in PoolingClientConnectionManager thread safe?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm planning on using the [closeIdleConnections](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager.html#closeIdleConnections(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method in the `PoolingClientConnectionManager` class, but first wanted to make sure that it was thread safe.  I.e. a request won't be granted a connection or cause weird synchronization errors while the `closeIdleConnections` method is running.  Or do I have to implement thread safety manually using synchronized code blocks/methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interface method, and the [Javadoc for the interface](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager.html#closeIdleConnections(long)) says

> implementations of this interface must be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks; sorry didn't see it